# Bigquery : How to retrieve data for a column according to another column's value

Tags: google-bigquery

Can you help with this bigquery issue i am having?

Lets suppose i have this table :

[image]

what i want to do :

```
if id =1, select element1 
if id =2, select element2
if id =3, select element3
if id =4, select element4
if id =5, select element5
```

I have to do that on each line but dont want to do switch/case because i have a tons of columns and i am just supposed to know how they start : "element".
Is there a way to do this like :

```
select id, concat("element",id) as right_element
from mytable
```

I know it doesnt work as i would get for the first line for example :

"2, element3" instead of "2, xxx" xxx being the value of the element3 where id=3.

can you help please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach

```
select *,
  regexp_extract(to_json_string(t), r'"element' || id || '":"([^""]*)"') result
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample (slightly modified for better visiibility) data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thnak you very muche Mikhail. This is exactly what i was looking for.